# .how to get top 5 most occurring names in a column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

My Dataframe looks something like this.

[image]

I need to find top 5 most occurring names in Name column of this table

Comment: read [ask].....

Comment: We aren't going to write the code for you, first and foremost. Please check over what the illustrious @eyllanesc recommended, as well as take the [tour of the site](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Stack overflow is a place for code problems. You haven't given us a problem to solve, you've given us a job to do. There's a difference. Please also provide a [minimal, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you've tried.

Comment: `return ['Emma', 'Madison', 'Hannah', 'Grace', 'Emily`]` should do it

Answer (score 0):

try

```
Dataframe.Name.value_counts().head()
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
vals = Dataframe.Name.value_counts().head()
vals.keys()
```